# Get layout positions without actually moving nodes

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Can I get nodes position after running layout without actually changing positions?

The `layout.run()` function will make the actual transition but just I want to get the target coordinates without any node movement.

The problem is that I want to create a smooth animation which first involves running a layout and some hooks afterwards.

Neither `transform` parameter of a layout nor the `eles.layoutPosition` can be used in my case because the former is provided before the actual layout computation and the latter is for writing extensions.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything better than just run layout save the new coordinates and restore pre-layout state. Looks like this

```
cy.batch(function() {
    lyt.initPositions = lyt.options.eles.map(function(ele){return {x:ele.position().x, y:ele.position().y}})
    lyt.on('layoutstop', function() {
        lyt.options.eles.forEach(function(ele, currentIndex) {
            finalPositions[currentIndex] = {x:ele.position().x,
                                            y:ele.position().y}
            ele.position(lyt.initPositions[currentIndex])
        })
        lyt.finalPositions = finalPositions
    })
    lyt.run()
})
```